# Have installed ILNumerics into VisualStudio 2012, no "Computing Module" is available

Tags: visual-studio-2012, module, installation, ilnumerics

Starting with a fresh install of Visual Studio, I used NuGet console to "Install-Package ILNumerics".

I create a new Windows Form project, added a reference to ILNumerics.dll and I can use ILNumerics, so that's fine. However, some of the getting started documentation references a "Computing Module" that I should add to my project. The problem is that I don't see anything like this in the "Add New Item" dialog when it opens up. I also had to manually add the ILNumerics widgets to the Toolbox (i.e. clicking "Choose Items. . ." and then loading ILNumerics.dll).

Can someone please explain how I can get the "Computing Module" widget to appear in my "Add New Item" dialog? Thanks.

Comment: Which language? Computing Modules are only available for C# currently?

Answer (score 0):

nuget packages of Ilnumerics are obsolete now. Go to http://ilnumerics.net/download.html and install ILNumerics Ultimate VS. The ILNumerics Visual Studio Extension installs a Computing Module and the Visualization Module templates in C#.

Docu: http://ilnumerics.net/Getting-Started-with-ILNumerics.html